# SSRS How to limit the number of group rows per page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

I have a SSRS report with dataset as follows:

Record 1 Item 001 Qty 10 Category A
Record 2 Item 002 Qty 10 Category A
Record 3 Item 003 Qty 10 Category B
Record 4 Item 004 Qty 10 Category B
Record 5 Item 005 Qty 10 Category B

I Add Group by Category (group G1) and hide rows of Item 001, Item 002, and so on. So the report displayed 2 rows as below:

Category A   Qty 20 Category row 1
Category B   Qty 30 Category row 2

To limit maximum rows per page, I add parent group (group G2). And with G2 group expression of "Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/10)", but it did not count/return 10 rows of category, but still count 10 rows of Item 001, 002, ...

I tried to change my G2 group expression to "=Int((RunningValue(Fields!Category.Value,CountDistinct, "T1")-1)/10)",
but it gave me error "Unable to issue because there is no layout file" when running the report.

Please advise, so that I can limit rows per one page, if the visible rows are the Category rows (not the Item rows).
Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code the code blocks

Comment: Your expression is limiting grouping the number of GROUPS, not the number of detail lines in the group.  It would be easier to add the ROW_NUMBER to the data in the SQL partitioned by Category so you have a number list of items that you can group by with a similar GROUP expression `=Int((Fields!Category.ROW_NUM.Value-1)/10)`

Comment: Thank you @Hannover Fist for your feed back. But we use application package system, which we do not have access to change the SQL query. So we can only use existing dataset in the RDLC file.